# Swift date from string always returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have a date that is a string that looks like this:

`Apr 25 2018 12:00AM`

What I am trying to do is convert this date format to yyyy-MM-dd and then convert it back to a string, I have a tried the following:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "M dd yyyy h:mm A"
            let SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate = formatter.date(from: tableDic["SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate"] as! String)
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            let SLAIssuedFinalGradingDateString = formatter.string(from: SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate!)
```

But `SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate` always returns nil, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the others have described, or `MMM d yyyy h:mma` is sufficient. But the question is how did you get a string in the format of `Apr 25 2018 12:00AM`, because it invites all sorts of confusion about locales: Is your UK user going to see date portion as `25 Apr 2018`? Is your French speaking user going to see `Apr` in French? Is your Chinese using even going to see the year as `2018`? Usually we use ISO 8601/RFC 3339 dates to avoid this silliness. I always get nervous when I see a question that says "I want to convert this localized string to `Date` object" ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `dateFormat` for `Apr 25 2018 12:00AM` is not right. You are using `M dd yyyy h:mm A`, but format would be `MMM dd yyyy hh:mma`.
[Use this link to check date format](http://nsdateformatter.com/).

Code Should be:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale =  Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy hh:mma"
let SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate = formatter.date(from: tableDic["SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate"] as! String)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let SLAIssuedFinalGradingDateString = formatter.string(from: SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate!)
```

Comment: The locale also needs to be set to `en_US_POSIX` otherwise people with non-English locales won't be able to parse the English month names.

Comment: @rmaddy setting locale worked. I think apple devs didn't try to fix this issue cuz objective-c also has the similar issue in using time APIs without setting locale.

Comment: @KoreanXcodeWorker There's nothing to fix. It's not a bug.

Comment: @rmaddy Apple should notice the requirement of setting locale in using Date APIs in Apple Developer if there is nothing to fix since it returns nil. There is no any official guides of that requirement. There are some posts written regarding this issue(called a BUG by some), eg,. http://stephentolton.com/nsdateformatter-24-hour-time-and-region-formats/

Answer (score 0):

Your `dateFormat` string is incorrect. A `DateFormatter` will always return nil if the dateFormat string does not match the supplied string.

`"MMM dd yyyy hh:mma"`

This is what you're after. I suggest you review a DateFormatter [cheat sheet](https://waracle.com/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/) and familiarise yourself with the symbols.

Comment: The locale also needs to be set to `en_US_POSIX` otherwise people with non-English locales won't be able to parse the English month names.

Comment: Also, you need to set `en_US_POSIX` because on devices with 24h time the format would be overwritten to `HH:mm` otherwise. Also you should make sure to specify the timezone for both formatters otherwise strange things might happen.